# Free service for email addresses on my own domain with IMAP/POP access

Tags: email

I've been using Zoho Mail for all my side projects. When you get a domain, they used to offer an awesome free plan to start using email.

I've started another project, but this time, when I signed up to get my email, I realised Zoho has changed their free plan, and now they don't give you access to your account through IMAP/POP.

This is why I'm trying to find an alternative to Zoho Mail, I'd appreciate any recommendation.

Basically, what I need is a service where I can get email accounts (more than 5 free if possible) with my own domain.

Comment: Why not gmail ?

Comment: can you get emails with your own domain on gmail?

Comment: Yea sure, that's actually possible with GMail. You can import mails via POP3 and send mails from another email address. (Settings -> Accounts and Import). Though this might not be the right solution for you…

Comment: Zoho still allows [POP](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/pop-access.html) for existing free accounts, but [not for new ones](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/subscription.html#alink0). I'm a little confused about [IMAP](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/imap-access.html) since it's two-way and they seem to allow it for [migration](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/pop-imap-migration.html) *to* Zoho.

Comment: @sondra.kinsey, migration is from another IMAP to Zoho, not the other way around. So Zoho IMAP still not enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to host your own email on your own domain? There are three packages I know of that seem pretty good for that:

https://mailinabox.email/

Mailinabox is a Ubuntu based mail system, fully open source. Con: It's not systemd ready, so you need older Ubuntu systems (at least last I checked).

https://github.com/tomav/docker-mailserver

Docker-mailserver is a fully open source Docker based system to host email. Any system you can run docker on should be fine. Con: Initial configuration can be confusing and certain scenarios seem trickier than they should be. (Mail at mail.example.org: no problem; mail at example.org: problem.)

https://poste.io/

Free docker based mail system. Con: All of the components are open source, but the docker build method isn't. There's a paid version with more features, too. (That may be a pro or a con for some people, but not likely what you want.)